# How much ether do I need to generate 400 million tokens?

Tags: ether, tokens, erc-20

I want to create an ether token. I was wondering how much ether do I need to generate 400 million tokens.

Comment: There is not enough information. Do you want to make a smart contract?

Comment: @Andromelus. Yes I want to make a smart contract

Comment: > I want to generate 400 million tokens each token worth of $1 or $2 Is this a joke ?

Comment: @betcheg. I am in the learning phase. If you know, please answer.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20207)

Comment: It doesn't cost much it is just a number inside a contract. Deploying a contract can be expensive but if you are not in a hurry you can deploy one for less than usd$10. Developing, auditing and mantaining contracts is much more expensive than deploying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The amount of ether it takes to deploy a token contract does not depend on how many tokens there will be.

I.e., your contract will look something like this:

```
contract MyToken {
    uint256 public totalSupply = 10; // or 1000 or 4**24
    ...
}
```

What number you store in `totalSupply` does not affect the gas consumed by deploying the contract.

Comment: Thanks. How to set the value of the token in smart contract? Will gas consumes based on the value of my token?

Comment: Define what you mean by "the value of the token?" If the contract is going to sell the token, then you can enforce a price in the function that people use to buy the token. No, the consumed gas does not depend on the price you set. If you mean the value on exchanges, that's set by market demand.

Comment: I mean value of the token is the worth of the token initially like $1 or $2. I want to generate 400 million tokens each token worth of $1 or $2.

Comment: You would need an oracle to check what's the current ETH price in USD. Blockchain does not know about exchange rates. Also you may create a contract method to set current exchange rate, which you (and only you) can call and adjust the price daily, hourly (but this will cost you gas)

Answer (score 0):

you can generate the tokens by deploying a smart contract however to make them worth $1 that is not possible

in order to generate value your token must

1. Have an actual utility or usage - you need to put forward a case on why anyone would want your token over the 1000's of other tokens being minted daily
2. once the use case is there you need some high profile investors on board to promote the project and bring some value
3. you need a good team to have a future development plan and assure anyone who will buy your token that you simply will not just sell your tokens and run off
4. good marketing always helps
5. after all this it may be possible to approach exchanges to list your tokens however each exchange have their own rules and regulations and will want the same assurances
6. once you have them listed on an exchange then maybe the tokens will generate some value
7. in the mean time they are just toy tokens :)